# with versus attach binding time

Tags: r

What accounts for this difference in the semantics of `with` versus `attach`?

```
> lst <- list(
 +     a  = 1,
 +     g = function() print(a)
 + )
 + with(lst, g())
 +
 Error in print(a) : object 'a' not found
!> attach(lst)
 + g()
 +
 > [1] 1 ## sought after behavior
```

Both put the objects in the argument list into a surrounding namespace, but it seems bindings occur at different times. I am trying to use lists to pass a list of parameters to a function. Eg,
`list(balance=20, get_balance=function()return(balance))`
might get passed to a function
`print_balance <- function(account) with(account, print(get_balance()))`. I know R now has some OOP subsystem but I can avoid learning/dealing with it if I can just use lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an option, depending on why you're looking to do what you are doing here:

```r
lst <- local({
  a <- 1
  g <- function() print(a)
  return(g)
})
lst()
# [1] 1
a
# Error: object 'a' not found
```

`with(lst, g())` won't work there, since `with` only works with lists and frames, whereas in this example `lst` *is the function `g`*.

If there is the potential need for multiple functions to have access to the same internal variables, then you can return a `list`:

```r
lst <- local({
  a <- 1
  g <- function() print(a)
  h <- function() print(a+10)
  list(g=g, h=h)
})
lst$g()
# [1] 1
lst$h()
# [1] 11
```

`with` works here:

```r
with(lst, g())
# [1] 1
with(lst, h())
# [1] 11
```

If you need a getter/setter scenario, realize that the internal functions can update the inner variables by using the `<<-` assignment operator (`<-` will not do what is needed):

```r
lst <- local({
  a <- 1
  get <- function() return(a)
  set <- function(val) {
    a <<- val
    invisible(a)
  }
  list(get = get, set = set)
})
lst$get()
# [1] 1
lst$set(99)
lst$get()
# [1] 99

with(lst, set(11))
with(lst, get())
# [1] 11
```

During all of this, `a` is not visible in the global environment.

Comment: Do you mind adding how this use of local() differs from just defining a function and returning the list?

Comment: This use of a `local` env is purely a one-off sort of thing; if you need multiple instances of this, you need to do the `local({...})` multiple times. Alternatively, you can write `makelst <- function() { a <- 1; ..., list(get=get,set=set); }` and then `lst <- makelst()`, and work with it in the same way.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. What I meant was, is there any reason to do "lst <- local({ ... list(get = get, set = set)})" over "lst <- function({ ... list(get = get, set = set)})". And then "with(lst(), get())".

Comment: What happens when you `with(lst(), get())` then `with(lst(), set(2))` then `with(lst(), get())`? (Hint: `set` does nothing, since the moment after it overwrites the value of the inner-variable `a`, its updated environment is discarded.) The `a <- 1` code is run each time you start with `with(list(), ...)`.

Comment: I see, just for changing state. That's fair, though not part of my original question, which is stateless.

Comment: Your use of `a` for preserving some value does not suggest mutability, certainly, I inferred that. I can't think (right now) of a solid reason for using that, but I assume there are good reasons for wanting that behavior. Yes, that was an assumption of mine, hope that doesn't crush things :-)